# Why is "Program Files" two words?

Tags: windows, command-line, directory, naming, history

Is there a history, or a reason, for the fact that the `Program Files` folders in Windows installations have a space in the title?

Why wasn't it called `Programs` or `Installations` or something that's *ONE* word (command line access, hello)?  It seems that there must be a good reason for this...does someone know?

Comment: Even worse. Compare `C:\Documents and Settings` with `/home` :)

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  Is there a reason for this?  I understand a bad marketing decision back in the day, but...it's not fixed? Something like "Old Sparky, who died in '92, made this decision, and now we keep it in his memory" or similar...

Comment: I want to rename that to `ALT+255` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Raymond Chen explains in [this TechNet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2006.08.windowsconfidential.aspx) that it was a voluntary decision:

- *Programs* are applications, seen as single units by the end users although they often consist of many files. They live in the Start menu, where they can easily be accessed, sorted, filtered, etc.
- *Program files* are the individual files making the programs. They're little more than implementation details, and the end users should not have to be bothered with them or even know they exist. Therefore, they live in a specific folder named `Program Files` instead of `Programs`.

Comment: +1 (and accept): Wow, that's EXACTLY the answer I was looking for.  I thought it would be futile!  Cheers!

Comment: (I wonder why they use a woman for their example of an un-savvy user?)

Comment: @Steve, I don't think that's supposed to be a woman (the article only says `a user`). The `she` pronoun may be used for courtesy there (instead of something like `s/he`). English is not my native language though, so I may be wrong about this.

Comment: Odd, this question was closed, because "We expect answers to generally involve facts, references" which is exactly what is here.

Comment: Does anyone else think it's a bit odd that the answer somewhat contradicts itself?  If "the individual files making the programs" are "little more than implementation details", couldn't the same be said of the folder in which those files reside?  I mean, if a user should not have to be bothered with the idea of a "program" consisting of multiple "program files" then why the hell do the semantics of the folder name matter?

Answer (score 0):

The name doesn't really matter as long as it is descriptive enough to convey what is stored there. Tab-completion makes command line access just as easy as changing to any other directory. If you really don't like it, you can change your default %ProgramFiles% path and well behaved applications won't have a problem with it.

I'd guess the typical user wouldn't have any trouble with it as they would normally use Windows Explorer to access that directory anyways and someone using the command line would most likely be savvy enough to navigate to it.

The biggest knock on that name was the length, not the space, with regards to FAT compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the actual reason or decision that was taken, but it did show how the 'Redmond reality distortion field' was at work.  There was a concept when this was introduced (in Windows 95) that windows could happily deal with spaces in folder names. Technically it could but it causes HUGE issues with any application that was written at the time and since.

Windows had a thing where you would get a ~ in a file name so it would work with older applications that didn't expect any spaces

```
c:\my long folder name\file.txt
```

would be

```
c:\mylong~1\file.txt
```

, but this didn't always work.  I have memories of getting the wrong file using the ~ notation if two files were named a simiar thing.

I think this was a case of someone in Microsoft saying of course we can have spaces in our folder names, everything will work fine and  not caring about the reality.

If thats not the case then why did we go from

- Documents and Settings

to

- Users

and the new ProgramData folder has no Spaces.  It was a bad decision, but has existed for too long to be changed.

Comment: "but has existed for too long to be changed" lol

Comment: the `~` thing only works if the files have shortnames. [Modern Windows doesn't generate shortnames by default for performance reasons](https://superuser.com/a/1505235/241386)